# Files in my resources directory are not being copied to classes dir using IntelliJ debug

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j2

This is my project.

The second image is my modules

When i build to run in debug the log4j2.properties is not being copied to the target-->classes directory, so the app can not find it

is there another setting i need to add?

Thank you for any help

[image: project]

[image: project2]

Comment: How do you build the app?

Comment: @Tashkhisi thanks .   i build the app using the default intellij build project button

Answer (score 0):

I ended up , just deleting the project.
importing from git and creating a new project.
It was acting weird until I invalidated the caches.

now all seems ok